# How to generalise access to struct fields?

Tags: rust

I try to find differences from two streams (represented by iterators) for later analysis, the code below works just fine, but looks a little bit ugly and error prone (copy-paste!) in updating values in `update_v?` functions. Is there any ways to generalise it assuming that source is matter?

```
struct Data {};

struct S {
    v1: Option<Data>,
    v2: Option<Data>
}

...

fn update_v1(diffs: &mut HashMap<u64, Data>, key: u64, data: Data) {
    match diffs.entry(key) {
        Entry::Vacant(v) => {
            let variant = S {
                v1: Some(data),
                v2: None
            };
            v.insert(variant);
        },
        Entry::Occupied(e) => {
            let new_variant = Some(data);
            if e.get().v2 == new_variant {
                e.remove();
            } else {
                let existing = e.into_mut();
                existing.v1 = new_variant;
            }
        }
    }
}

fn update_v2(diffs: &mut HashMap<u64, Data>, key: u64, data: Data) {
    match diffs.entry(key) {
        Entry::Vacant(v) => {
            let variant = S {
                v2: Some(data),
                v1: None
            };
            v.insert(variant);
        },
        Entry::Occupied(e) => {
            let new_variant = Some(data);
            if e.get().v1 == new_variant {
                e.remove();
            } else {
                let existing = e.into_mut();
                existing.v2 = new_variant;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing one function for each field, receive a pair of `Fn`s as arguments:

- `fn(&S) -> Option<Data>`, which can be used to replace this condition

  ```
  if e.get().v1 == new_variant { /* ... */ }
  ```

  with this

  ```
  if getter(e.get()) == new_variant { /* ... */ }
  ```
- `fn(&mut S, Option<Data>) -> ()`, which replaces

  ```
  existing.v2 = new_variant;
  ```

  with

  ```
  setter(&mut existing, new_variant);
  ```

Then on the call site you pass a couple lambdas like this

- Getter: `|d| d.v1`
- Setter: `|s, d| s.v2 = d`

Or vice-versa for the other function.

And if you want to keep the `update_v1` and `update_v2` function names, just write those as wrappers to this new generalized function that automatically pass the proper lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trait to facilitate different ways of accessing the structure.

```
trait SAccessor {
    type RV;
    fn new(Data) -> S;
    fn v2(&S) -> &Self::RV;
    fn v1_mut(&mut S) -> &mut Self::RV;
}

struct DirectSAccessor;

impl SAccessor for DirectSAccessor {
    type RV = Option<Data>;
    fn new(data: Data) -> S {
        S {
            v1: Some(data),
            v2: None
        }
    }
    fn v2(s: &S) -> &Self::RV {
        &s.v2
    }
    fn v1_mut(s: &mut S) -> &mut Self::RV {
        &mut s.v1
    }
}

fn update<A>(diffs: &mut HashMap<u64, S>, key: u64, data: Data) 
where A: SAccessor<RV=Option<Data>>
{
    match diffs.entry(key) {
        Entry::Vacant(v) => {
            let variant = A::new(data);
            v.insert(variant);
        },
        Entry::Occupied(e) => {
            let new_variant = Some(data);
            if A::v2(e.get()) == &new_variant {
                e.remove();
            } else {
                let existing = e.into_mut();
                *A::v1_mut(existing) = new_variant;
            }
        }
    }
}

// ...

// update::<DirectSAccessor>( ... );
```

[Full code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=04e91fca048f22627654579fa78a66a2&version=stable)

Comment: It seems a bit complicated for me, but anyway thanks for you answer!